# Include in user defined macro fails

Tags: macros

I'm trying to use `gpp` (Generic Preprocessor) to add some additional information before and after an `#include`. The code is as follows:

`\define{\code{filename}}{PRE \include{\filename} POST}
==> \code{./t.txt} <==`

And the output:

`$ gpp -T t.mkd -o t.out
t.mkd:2: error: Requested include file not found`

I'm thinking there's a problem with referencing `\filename` with `\include` as `\filename` will only be evaluated once `\code` is called while meta-macros will store their parameters at define time (If I understand the documentation correctly).

I've tried a bunch of different stuff, and while this is obviously a RTFM kind of question, my intended use of the tool is too limited to justify using a whole lot of time learning the tool (and not just try another preprocessor and another until one just works well enough - I started testing with gpp as it seems quite capable if we need more later).

PS: Sorry about the lack of relevant tags. I don't have enough reputation to create tags, and the only one that popped up was `macro`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get more useful responses for this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) than on SuperUser.

In the meantime, however, given that the latest version of [gpp](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) was released in 2004, it might be difficult to find people with expertise in it to assist you. If using another preprocessor would be an option, I'd suggest [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/), for which the GNU version is regularly updated and widely used -- especially as part of the GNU `autoconf` software. In `m4` the equivalent code (in the file `t.m4`) would be:

```
define(`code',`PRE include(`$1') POST')dnl
code(`./t.txt')
```

Given a file `t.txt` that reads:

```
This is the content of the file t.txt.
```

... the command `m4 t.m4` produces:

```
PRE This is the content of the file t.txt.
 POST
```

Comment: Guess we'll go with m4 then. They also have an installer for Windows users which is good. Thanks.